# При умножении элемента массива на 2 в некоторой степени получается неправильное число

Tags: c++

Нужно перевести целую часть числа в 2 системе счисления в 10 систему счисления без использования специальных библиотек. Отдельно всё считается правильно (элемент массива, степень), но при их умножении получается неверное значение.

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
int dl = 0, t = 0, cel = 0;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

char mas[N] = {};

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cin >> mas[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (mas[i] == '.') {
        t = i;
    }
}
cout << "Индекс точки " << t << endl << endl;

// 101.11 Длина 5. Точка индекс t=3. 1*2**0 + 0*2**1 + 1*2**2
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {  
    cel += mas[i] * pow(2, t - i - 1);
    cout << "Степень " << pow(2, t - i - 1) << endl;
    cout << "Элемент массива " << mas[i] << endl;
    cout << "Умножение " << int(mas[i]) * int(pow(2, int(t - i - 1))) << endl;
    cout << mas[i] << "*2^" << t - i - 1 << '=' << mas[i] * pow(2, t - i - 1) << endl;
}



return 0;
}
```

[image: Итог работы программы]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в умножении `int(mas[i]) * int(pow(2, int(t - i - 1)))`. Вы умножаете не на число, а на код символа. `int(mas[i])` равнозначно `int('1') == 49`. Отнимите от кода символа 48 - код ноля

```
int(mas[i]) // неправильно
// надо так
(mas[i] - 48) // отнимается от кода символа 
// или так
(mas[i] - '0')
```

Или переводите из `char` в `int` с помощью специальных функций.